# SQL UNION ALL against empty record set results in high full scans

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a view combining different tables with UNION ALL for a new dataset. Eg:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 'A' as type
FROM table A
WHERE <some filter>

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, 'B' as type
FROM table B
WHERE <some filter>

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, 'C' as type
FROM table C
WHERE <some filter>
....
```

A few different databases use this view, but one of them has a very high full scans/second (performance monitor).

The only difference is that problematic database has 0 records in one or more of the tables combined in the union all view. Commenting out those specific unions in the view reduces the full scans to virtually nothing.

The tables used do have indexes and statistics, and I tried updating/rebuilding them to no avail.

What could be causing this and how can it be avoided?

Comment: Do you mean you're seeing a full scan of a table with 0 records?

Comment: We would ideally need to have the complete table schema and index details plus the actual execution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)